# How to properly use Mapped type for function signature

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

depending on the type of a parameter I'd like to type the return. Similar to function overload, but using mapped types.

```
const requestX = async(
    id?: string | undefined,
): Promise<(typeof id) extends string ? X: X[]> =>
    fetch(......)
```

However, the return is always typed as `X[]`. What is the proper way to do it?

Comment: Overloads is the way to go here. You can get this working with conditional types only when parameter is provided https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAGlC8UDeUBmB7dAuKBnYATgJYB2A5lAL4DcAsAFAMAmEAxgDYCGB0r6J+KDwCOAVwj4YOADwAVKBAAewCCSa48hUhQA+UUWoipSEJgD4AFESYB+HLICUCM1AAKBdAFsiuCHIXKquqaxORQNrA4MADaALpmdIz0fALAUADu6AQA1hqIIuKSFgDknLhMxQ7UUAD0NW4e3r7SMGYMDCmCnOy46ADqWbkIQhBiEsAwFgYsxiSmVbX17l4+fjHx7cn8giToafmjhRMWC3UNK81weutmQA

Answer (score 1):

Unless you use overloads as suggested by Aleksey L., you need a generic type argument, otherwise `typeof id` is resolved statically to `string | undefined` which does not help in the mapping.

Generics example:

```
const requestX = async <ID extends string | undefined = undefined>(id?: ID)
    : Promise<ID extends string ? X : X[]> =>
    fetch(...);
    

const x = requestX() // Promise<X[]>
const y = requestX('123'); // Promise<X>
```